# How to pass input json with byte[] in web api postman

Tags: asp.net-web-api

```
{
"From":"donotreply@xxx.com",  "To":["abc@xxx.com"],
"Cc":["abc@xxx.com"],  "Bcc":["abc@xxx.com"],
"Subject":"Export",  "TemplateName":"Agent",
"EmailType":"Agent",  "Attachments":[{
"Name":"wifi.txt",    "Type":"txt",
"StreamData":{"NzI5OTk4NzgxNg0KDQoxIG0tNjczDQoNCjJtLTExMjINCjRtLTE1NzENCjgtMjE4Mw0KDQoxMDYxDQoNCjUwMCBtb2RlbSByZWZ1bmRhYmxl"}}]`    ``
}`input json``
```

I'm calling one method by passing this value as input json using postman, but the `StreamDate` value alone coming as `null`.

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Well it's an invalid JSON object.
`StreamData` has to be either a string or an object with a key.
Try

```
{
"From":"donotreply@xxx.com",  
"To":["abc@xxx.com"],
"Cc":["abc@xxx.com"],  
"Bcc":["abc@xxx.com"],
"Subject":"Export",  
"TemplateName":"Agent",
"EmailType":"Agent",  
"Attachments":[{
    "Name":"wifi.txt",
    "Type":"txt",
    "StreamData": "NzI5OTk4NzgxNg0KDQoxIG0tNjczDQoNCjJtLTExMjINCjRtLTE1NzENCjgtMjE4Mw0KDQoxMDYxDQoNCjUwMCBtb2RlbSByZWZ1bmRhYmxl"
}]
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

StreamData is a byte array.

How to pass byte array value into input json?

Comment: Write the data to a file and get its contents.

Comment: Can you share me some sample example for this?

Answer (score -1):

In the sending code Base64 encode the byte array into a string.